# Existe alguma maneira de autoajustar o site para celulares?

Tags: css, bootstrap

estou fazendo um mini-projeto onde no PC o mesmo não apresenta problemas na visualização da página. Mas quando testo no celular a coisa muda um pouco de figura, vejam o print dos dois testes por favor:

[image: Print 1]

[image: Print 2]

No primeiro a parte do painel fica ocupando o footer, o meu código é basicamente este:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
Conteúdo aqui.
</div></div>
```

Já no segundo o site fica todo deformado, a ponto de certos objetos desaparecerem da página. Existe algum ajuste ou script que posso usar para contornar esse problema? Obrigado desde já.

Comment: O site deverá ser responsivo, ou usando alguma biblioteca que auxilie como [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/), ou por código mesmo, como [medias queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries)

Comment: Olá Lucas, estou usando o bootstrap.

Comment: Boostrap tem o sistema de grid e o conceito mobile first, que basicamente é desenvolver primeiro pensando no móvel, pra depois dektop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe sim, você pode inclusive utilizar algum framework exemplo: Bootstrap.
Vou deixar um exemplo abaixo caso você não queira utilizar nenhum framework e fazer tudo na 'mão' :

```
/* Small devices ( @screen-sm-min Phones (<768px) ) */
@media (min-width: 368px) {

}

/* Small devices (@screen-sm-min tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {

}

/* Medium devices ( @screen-md-min desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) { 

}

/* Large devices ( @screen-lg-min large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```

Agora dentro de cada @media você pode alterar seus containers, elementos, etc... de acordo com a resolução.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu perfeitamente o meu problema!

Answer (score 1):

Está utilizando Bootstrap? Ok, ótimo!, Agora verifique a opção de grids que ele fornece, caso utilize ele irá se ajustar conforme selecionado.

Exemplo, em uma div, que você gostaria que em desktop seja 50%, pode utilizar a classe col-lg-6. Caso gostaria que no mobile ou em outras resoluções essa div seja de 100%, pode incluir a classe col-xs-12, ficando assim:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
```

Você pode verificar estas informações no seguinte link: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Lembrando que também pode utilizar @media para ajustar conforme a resolução de tela desejado:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 500px){}
```